# How to save data from API temporary in device Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I open my apps, every time I need to wait for it loading the data from API. I want to save data on Local Storage temporary to make app works offline and also can load the data faster. I want to get data from api, json data and save them to local storage. Can I know what method or can use any package? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `Shared Preference`.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` or `Hive`. I would suggest you to use `Hive`

Comment: Use SQLite to load data when offline and update data when online then use it from SQLite

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using SharedPreferences + JSON. For example, you may have a user object:

```
class User {

  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    };
}
```

Then what you need to do is:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("user", jsonEncode(user));
```

And to recover the object:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
User user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("user")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I add my code above already. Can I know where I need to put the SharedPreferences?

Comment: @dipgirl: You can do that after requesting data from API. In your code, inside `response.statusCode == 200` condition.

Comment: @Ampersanda, ok I try it. Thank you

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
I have error at this line User user = User.fromJson(prefs.getString("user");.

Comment: Soory, @dipgirl I had done a mistake on my answer. The correct line is:     
User user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(prefs.getString("user")));

Comment: @ViníciusAssisNeves I already change and add to my code, but it still not working

Comment: no error, but become no output. It always show loading only

Comment: @ViníciusAssisNeves sorry, I just saw the error is "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'"